# How do I make the field searchable?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the elasticsearch index with data stored inside. I want to make queries using some of the fields. The problem is that some fields are non-searchable. Here are some information about the mapping structure:

```
"bdate": {
    "type": "string",
    "store": true
    },
"c": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "no",
    "store": true
}
```

I understand, that since there is `"index":"no"` field attached to `"c"`, I can not write queries using this field. But how should I change `"index"` from `"no"` to another value to get the ability to write needed queries?

My Elasticsearch version is 1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your mappings. You cant change mapping of an existing field.

You need to reindex your index, to do that:
1) create a new index (empty)
2) create the new mappings on this new index
3) reindex your data from your existing index to your new on. You can use:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "an url if your are not on the same server, if you use the same one on localhost for example: http://localhost:9200"
    },
    "index": "oldindex"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "newindex"
  }
}
```